# Does it matter which trapper I sell legendary items to?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

So far, I've discovered two trappers, and I know that when I sell legendary items to one of the trappers I am able to buy items crafted by him.

Do the trappers pool  - so selling to one makes the fur available at all other locations? Or does selling to one mean that items created legendary fur is available only at that one location.

I ask because I noticed that some items require multiple furs to be available, and i don't want to split my resources, but would also like to avoid traipsing over the whole map with each legendary kill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a whole, the game recognizes the unique nature of legendary pelts. They are the only pelts who do not despawn from your horse when you die before handing them it. (Well, they do despawn but they get teleported to the trapper).

If a player were to split their trapper inventory, that would be an irreversible game breaking bug.

Secondly, [following this guide's description](https://www.metabomb.net/off-meta/gameplay-guides/red-dead-redemption-2-trapper-locations-guide), **there is only one trapper**, who simply appears in multiple locations.